# GP and combinations divisibility

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinations, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Is the number :

${100 \choose 0}\cdot2^0 + {100 \choose 1}\cdot2^1+{100 \choose 2}\cdot2^2+{100 \choose 3}\cdot2^3 \ldots + {100 \choose 100}\cdot2^{100}$

divisible by 3?

I tried looking at the first few terms which can be written as :

$2^0 + \frac{100}{1}\cdot 2^1 + \frac{100 \cdot 99}{2!}\cdot2^2+\frac{100 \cdot 99\cdot98}{3!}\cdot2^3+\ldots$

So I my guess it that the general term

$a_n = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^n 100-i}{n!}\cdot2^n$

but I am not sure how to continue from here to obtain the final value and check if it is divisible by 3. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: write the binomial  expansion of $${(1+2)}^{100}$$
Do you see a similarity?

Comment: Oh my this is simply the binomial expansion of $(1+2)^{100}$ so dividing it by 3 is just $3^{99}$?

Comment: @JarnaSadeep yes of course!

Comment: I feel so silly now for trying to look for a general term formula to sum it up. XD Thank you!